# What are other ways of finding Max and Min in python, other from my method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How my method works is by sorting the list of numbers from least to greatest, finds the length of the list, then pick the first and last index integers. In the python world is this efficient or is there a better faster way; speed-wise?

```
list = [11,2,343,32324,324,23456,437575,23534654,34624,236543,45464,549874984,4654      ,987498,654684,41654,684,4,56498,146,4984,0,-1,-58,54,-100]

list.sort()
x = len(list)
max = list[x-1]
min = list[x-x]

print(max)
print(min)
```

Comment: The best way depends on program context, and there is no program context here. If you show your full program we might be able to help.

Comment: This has many forms of badness.  `list`, `max` and `min` all shadow the builtin functions `list()`, `max()` and `min()`.  `x` does not convey any useful meaning. `list[len(list)-1]` is more concisely written as `list[-1]`.  Finally, `list[x-x]` is just ... wrong.

Comment: In Python especially, always look for a built-in function for tasks that seems simple and common, such as `min` and `max`

Answer (score 3):

The `sort()` method has complexity \$\mathcal{O(n \log n)}\$ (or worse) whereas the built-in `max()` and `min()` functions are linear (\$\mathcal{O}(n)\$) in the size of the list.

The Pythonic and efficient way is IMHO as follows:

```py
def min_max(arr):
    return min(arr), max(arr)
```

I gave an introductory talk for high-school audience with this very example! Fell free to use [this notebook](https://github.com/romulusFR/expose-science-informatique/blob/main/code/minmax.ipynb).

Answer (score 2):

As @Romuad notes, use the built-in `min` and `max` functions.

This isn't an algorithms Q/A (maybe see [CS StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) for that), but since it's so common and so simple, here's the basic algorithm that those built-in functions implement:

```py
def max(values: List[int]):
    max_so_far = -float('inf')
    for v in values:
        if v > max_so_far:
            max_so_far = v
    return v
```

This is how you get O(n) performance--that is, you only touch each element in the list once, whereas sorting requires comparisons, so you need to look at each element more than once).

Note that the implementation of `min` is basically the same as the above, but with several obvious things inverted.

Thought exercise: see if you can compute both `min` and `max` while only looping through the array once.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that such site exist

Comment: I would quibble about what the max of an empty list should be. `None` would be a more appropriate answer than `-inf`.

Comment: @200_success Yeah, this implementation is _terrible_, it's just a simple demo of the rough overall algorithm. It's worth reiterating, *don't use the above, and in general don't write this yourself: use the built-in capabilities.*